# ObservableCollection + ICollectionView = ObservableCollectionView?

Tags: wpf, data-binding, observablecollection, listcollectionview

I have a View Model that exposes an ObservableCollection. Now I want to add grouping and therefore want to use a View class, like e.g. the ListCollectionView. But that is not a generic type. Also, if I construct a ListCollectionView from an ObservableCollection, then it is not updated when the ObservableCollection is.

Did someone implement an ObservableCollection-backed View-collection somewhere?

If not, is it possible to achieve this dynamism somehow by using XAML?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need a specific implementation ; a `CollectionView` is just a view of a collection. You can get the default `CollectionView` for a collection using `CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView`:

```
ObservableCollection<Something> collection = ...
ICollectionView view = CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(collection);
```

Comment: GetDefaultView() is a thread-static method. You have to call it in your constructor method.